# Generate walking directions with Maps app iOS

Tags: google-maps, ios, map-directions

As of now, I successfully generate directions with Maps app from my app with the following code :

```
NSString *formattedGroceryAddress = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",((EnhancedUIActionSheet *)actionSheet).grocery.address] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
NSString *routeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",localDataHelper.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,localDataHelper.userLocation.coordinate.longitude,formattedGroceryAddress];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:routeString]];
```

It opens the Maps app with the appropriate **driving** directions. The thing is, I'd like to open Maps with the **walking** directions by default. Maybe I can pass another parameter in my request to do that.

Anybody knows how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well I guess I should have searched better before asking !

You can add dirflg=w to the request and it will launch maps app in the walking mode.

It's funny because Apple says they are only supporting a few Google Maps parameters not including this one but it actually seems to work !

For more info on Google Maps parameters : http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters
For more info on Maps links from iOS apps : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: hey bro.. the link  works for me but now i have an issue that i can't get back to my application from  where i called the map's app .Any idea??

Comment: Here is a working url of apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html